# Linking a 'table view' object to a Postgres table

Tags: python, pyqt, tableview, qt-designer

I posted a similar question to this yesterday and dschulz kindly responded, directing me towards a number of online articles. Unfortunately, I'm still struggling because either example code is in C++, whereas I'm using Python (although I think I've managed to make the necessary adjustments okay), the examples are not complete enough for me, or the code just isn't working. I'm new to programming so working through this software I'm making is progressing very slowly.

I've created a plugin in Quantum GIS that carries out a variety of spatial analyses. The plugin, once clicked, opens up a GUI with 4 tabs pertaining to 4 separate analyses. In one tab I would like to have a table view showing the results of a query on a table I have in Postgres. There is a 'calculate' button that once clicked, runs a query to update the database using some inputs on the same tab. At all times I would like there to be a table view along side this button showing what's happening in this table.

I have been using QT Designer to make the GUI, so I've figure out how to drag and drop widgets like sliders and check boxes that when altered can trigger events. I have found the 'table view' widget but have no idea how to link it to a query in the postgres database. The table view would be a receiver of a signal I assume, but I can't identify a 'slot' that would seem to display the Postgres query in the table view. I'm also having troubles successfully creating a QSqlQueryModel. What I have so far is this.

```
try:
      db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
      db.setHostName("localhost")
      db.setDatabaseName("database")
      db.setUserName("postgres")
      db.setPassword("password")
      db.open()
  except:
      #This exception does not run so I assume the link to the database worked out.
      QMessageBox.information(None, "Cancel", "Cannot Connect to Database to create table view.")
      return

  try:
      model = QSqlQueryModel()
      model.setQuery("SELECT name, density, deveff FROM susip." +str(filename)+ "_rezoning")          
  except:
      #Here the exception runs, which tells me that something is wrong with the setQuery function
      QMessageBox.information(None, "Cancel", "Cannot connect run query in database to create table view.")
      return

  model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
  model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Density")
  model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "DevEff")

  view = QTableView()
  view.setModel(model)
  view.show()
```

After running this by clicking the 'calculate' button and commenting out the model.seta new window briefly flashes and then disappears. Even if this did work, however, I don't see how I can get this table view to appear in the table view widget I placed in the gui. Second, I don't understand what's wrong with the query and why the 'try' statement is failing and giving me the 'except' statement that provides the QMessageBox.

I've searched through online documents endlessly and am totally lost. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a million,

Roman

Comment: Have you checked the PostgreSQL log for error messages?

Comment: No, I haven't checked the log but I've run the same query directly in Postgres (albeit with the filename specified) and its works fine...

Comment: It might be worth a look, just in case the statement isn't being created exactly as you expect, or there is something subtly different in the connection environment one way or the other.

Comment: Remove the `try/except` and post the traceback. You are hiding the real exception that would help identifying the real cause. Also is this inside a function? That would explain the 'flashing' part.

Comment: I've tried it within a 'click button' function and outside of it but get the same results. If it's an issue with the connection to Postgres then it could be the line "db.open()". The C++ documentation said to carry this out by typing "bool ok = db.open()" so I figured the python equivalent would be "db.open()", but I may be wrong. I'm getting familiar with python but C++ is very foreign to me.